# How does Uber auto-populate the registration page?

Tags: android

I installed Uber on my Android phone, and when I went to register my first/last name, email address, and phone number were already in the registration form.

How does this functionality occur?

Answer (score 0):

Probabily using AccountManager....

```
final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
final Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
final int size = accounts.length;
String[] names = new String[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 names[i] = accounts[i].name;
}
```

for more check [this----](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client) and [this](https://github.com/jehy/Android-GetOwnerInfo/blob/master/Android-get-owner-contact-info.java)